# How to test HTML5 game

Tags: html, testing

I'm new to web development. I have a small HTML55 game for kids. I was wondering how I can test an HTML5 game? What I need to keep in mind while testing?

How I can test a loading speed? What else I need to keep in mind while testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind different things:

- Is the game intuitive? (controls)
- Is the game smooth?
- Is your UI not too full of elements?
- Is the user well-guided in your game, can he get stuck easily or not?

For loading speed, there is different libraries and so, but this one seems nice: https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js

Answer (score 1):

Test every browser and OS you can get your hands on.  Test mobile devices as well.  In fact, you should absolutely make SURE it runs on mobile.  Go as far as to create specific pages designed to fit mobile screens.